# Fill in the column by comparing several columns of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
                       df1
    year   month    week   region    code    Quantity   
0   2017     6       22      ZZ      1700      7000
1   2017     8       28      TT      1780      4000
...

                       df2
    year    week    region    code     supply
0   2017     20       ZZ      1700      NaN 
1   2017     21       ZZ      1700      NaN 
2   2017     22       ZZ      1700      NaN
3   2017     23       ZZ      1700      NaN
4   2017     24       ZZ      1700      NaN
...
```

The `df1` is usually small, and the `df2` is huge. I need to fill `supply` column in `df2` with values from `Quantity` column from `df1` based on equal values in the columns `year`, `week`, `region`, `code` in both dataframes.

I wrote the condition:

`df2['supply'] = df2['year'].isin(df1['year']) & df2['week'].isin(df1['week']) & df2['region'].isin(df1['region']) & df2['code'].isin(df1['code'])`

He gives me `True` or `False`.  But I can't fill `supply` column based on this condition.

I tried:

```
df2['supply'] = df1['Quantity'].where(df2['year'].isin(df1['year']) & df2['week'].isin(df1['week']) & df2['region'].isin(df1['region']) & df2['code'].isin(df1['code']))
```

I thought to write a loop using my condition, but I don't know how to do it.

Please, help me understand where I am wrong?

Comment: Did my solution work for you? Let me know if you have a follow-up question.

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan  Yes, it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is doing a `pd.merge`
First, drop the "supply" column on df2.

After you do the merge you will get a Quantity column in df3 with the correct value for matching rows and a NaN value for rows in df2 with no matching rows in df1.

```
 df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on = ['year','week','region','code'], how = 'outer')
```

You can then either drop NaN values or fill them with a default using `dropna` or `fillna`